# How do I use Aptana 3 Bundles

Tags: aptana

This is probably really obvious, but how do I use bundles in Aptana 3? I've installed some using the commands menu such as jQuery, but how do I get it to use the code suggest feature? Do I need to copy it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make them *contribute*, you can directly edit the bundle under the rubbles directory.

On Windows, it will typically be present under

```
%USERPROFILE%\Aptana Rubles
```

I had to find a way of changing the quotes in jQuery autocomplete from single to double. I managed this by editing the `snippets.rb` under the below path.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Aptana Rubles\javascript-jquery.ruble\snippets\snippets.rb
```

After editing, be sure to flush cache (`Commands > Bundle Development > Flush Bundle Caches`) and restart Aptana Studio 3.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, bundles (like jQuery) contribute snippets, but don't (yet) contribute the jQuery API to the content assist feature. That is an upcoming feature.

To get jQuery content assist, follow the steps here, which basically involves copying a file into your project.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support